# how to check whether the characters in a word is mentioned in group of various character representing text boxes

Tags: c#

[image]

I had seven randomly character generated text boxes (which are grouped above in the picture) and a text box for to entering the word (which is there in the below).
Now the validations are if I entered these words:

1) fox: it should not allow this word because it must contains the middle word which is in yellow color at least one time

```
            string holdWord = textBox1.Text; //
            char charToCheck = Convert.ToChar(textBox3.Text); // 'a'
            bool result = holdWord.Contains( charToCheck ); //false
```

I use this code and it works.

2) fat: It should not allow this word because t is not mentioned in any of the text boxes above and it should return that letter as a error showing that this letter is not there) the word should be formed based on the above seven text boxes only

Comment: nice story bro. whats your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So 2) is your only open requirement.

```
// presuming textBox1-textBox6 are the textboxes for the letters 
// and textBox7 is the TextBox "Type your word"
TextBox[] textBoxes = { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6 };
string wordTyped = textBox7.Text;
var notContainedLetters = wordTyped
    .Where(c => !textBoxes.Any(txt => txt.Text.Contains(c)));

string notContained = String.Concat( notContainedLetters );
MessageBox.Show("These letters are in no textbox: " + notContained);
```

You need to add `using System.Linq` for the LINQ query.

You can use `notContained.Length > 0` or `Enumerable.Any` to check if there is at least one missing letter:

```
bool anyMissing = notContainedLetters.Any();
```

Comment: @Banana: has he mentioned something different??

Comment: This appears to neglect that the word _must_ contain the char in the middle textbox, though it isn't quite clear what is being asked

Comment: @VisualMelon this would be 1) which op got covered

Comment: @VisualMelon: the middle textbox was relevant only for the first requirement which is already solved by OP (a fact which makes the question confusing).

Comment: @TimSchmelter apologies, I must say those numbers were confusing me rather

Comment: For what its worth, you may want to just have a string array since you only care about the text :)

Comment: @Sayse: probably, but maybe the next question is how to get the textbox(es) which contains the word in the middle ;) So why losing informations for no reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
        char[] originalLetters = { 'F', 'O', 'D','J', 'X'}; // Add TextBox lettes in this array
        string enteredWord = "FAT"; //User Entered Word

        foreach (char letter in enteredWord)
        {
            // check if letter can be found withinenteredWord
            if (!originalLetters.Contains(letter))
            {
                //// Do Something
            }
        }
```